# Doctrine array of values in nested like clause

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to update a Doctrine query to accept an array of values to search on a field. I need them to be case insensitive matches so I'm using like clauses, otherwise I could just use `in` which would make things much simpler. What I want to end up with is a query like like:

```
"SELECT * FROM tableName t WHERE (t.option LIKE "option1" OR t.option LIKE "option2" OR t.option LIKE "option3");
```

So I tried the following:

```
function getItems( $options = array() ) {

    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->from('tableName', 't')
        ->select('t');

        $conditions = $qb->expr()->orX();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $conditions->add($qb->expr()->like('option', $option));
        }
        $qb->andWhere($conditions);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}

getItems( array('option1','option2','option3') );
```

But the values don't get escaped so you end up with a query like the below which throws an error:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName t WHERE (t.option LIKE option1 OR t.option LIKE option2 OR t.option LIKE option3)
```

This is normally where you would use named parameters like:

```
$qb->expr()->like('option', ':option');
$qb->setParameter( 'option', $option );
```

But you can't set the same parameter name multiple times with an array of values. I'm probably missing something obvious, bit of a novice with doctrine. Any ideas?

Comment: First, you can use `->where(' A LIKE "B" ')`, second, you can escape your `$option` in the `foreach` before passing to `like()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the literal expression:

```
$conditions->add($qb->expr()->like('option', $qb->expr()->literal($option)));
```